# exporting blender ABC to 3DsMAX with working Material ID

Tags: export, alembic

Well the question lives between blender and max community so I need to ask here just in case somebody also knows the answer.

When exporting objects ( a cube ) with different 3 materials assigned to the faces from Blender in Alembic, once I import in MAX the Material IDs goes nonsense.

I even tried with Vray proxy, and also happened the same.

Then I read the documentation of Alembic and also noticed that we had some troubles also from Houdini to Max.

Alembic won't write the Material IDs by default and we had to force it  in Houdini so MAX understands that.
We could find a workaround for Houdini. but I'm a bit stuck with the Blender 3DsMax connection.

By the way FBX works fine, but the implementation for references feels not so clean, and we were hoping to be able to use ABC for the neat reference upgrade.

Anyone knows something about it? is there another ABC exporter for Blender that speaks MAX better?

Answer (score 0):

there is several steps to achieve that:

1. Export the material with OBJ format from Blender (this one using Blender version 2.92)

Warning: if there is an error "error in file: meshName = shapeName" when importing OBJ in 3dsmax, when export OBJ choose "Limit to selection only", if the mesh contain more than 1 object make duplicate then combine all these into 1 object, the aim here is to populate all material into 1 multimaterial
[image]

2. Import that OBJ in 3dsmax to get the material
   turn on checkbox 'Import Materials'
   [image]

now you will get all material ID in 3dsmax
[image]

3. Export alembic (ABC) file from blender
   turn on checkbox 'Face Sets' when exporting
   [image]
4. Import alembic (ABC) in 3dsmax
   [image]
5. Apply that multi material to ABC in 3dsmax
   [image]
6. Setup these materials based on your render engine in max