# export looped alembic files

Tags: animation, alembic

Is it possible to export looped alembic files? I exported then imported an alembic object (a deer) from Blender into 3Ds Max sing this method that maintains working IDs: [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149520/exporting-blender-abc-to-3dsmax-with-working-material-id](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149520/exporting-blender-abc-to-3dsmax-with-working-material-id%C2%A0) . It came into Max as many alembic objects. Somehow I imported one early, since deleted, that I was able to loop with out of range controllers, but I can not loop this one. Any ideas?

Comment: If it worked, and you need to proof a concept, start from scratch with a new blend and simple cube and continue with a new max file. If it will be working, you can asume it is issue specific to your WIP file. In that case we need more info about your setup (or to see file) ... but it can be also an issue of Max, so you would have to ask there maybe. What do you mean loop alembic? Animation?

Comment: By looping an amblemic,  I mean repeating the animation indefinitely. So for example a 250 frame walking animal will walk forward indefinitely.

Comment: I don't have a Max, but this answer works for me - [Loop Alembic in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78701/2214)